# How to implement default activity (fragment) on app load. (Drawer Layout)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am using fragments and have successfully set up all the activities. Everything is fully functional.

My issue is that I can't seem to have a default layout or fragment class load when the app starts up initially.

I have tried a few methods with weird results. Here is my code from `MainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;


    if (id == home) {
        fragment = new Home();
    } else if (id == services) {
        fragment = new Services();
    } else if (id == beforeAfter) {
        fragment = new BeforeAfter();
    } else if (id == staff) {
        fragment = new Staff();
    } else if (id == patientInfo) {
        fragment = new Patient();
    } else if (id == blog) {
        fragment = new Blog();
    } else if (id == contactUs) {
        fragment = new Contact();
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = 
        getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
}
```

This is my fragment code for Home.class

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, null);

}
```

}

After editing my `MainActivity` java file and appending `onCreate` with

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.screen_area, new Home());
    ft.commit();
```

It now works. I guess I was assigning the name of the XML layout page for Home fragment instead of the ID of the FrameLayout under content_main.

Comment: your code looks fine, add your activity_main.xml file

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine. I guess the problem is in your `activity_main.xml`

make sure you have only two childs inside the `DrawerLayout`
one for your main container and one the `NavigationView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/nav_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

you need to show your fragments inside `onCreate`

```
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new YourFragment());
    ft.commit(); //important
```

Comment: After appending the fragment in onCreate, the app crashes at launch Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a004e (com.example.computer.finaltedford:id/home) for fragment Home{bbcc3cb #0 id=0x7f0a004e}

Comment: add your fragment files.

Comment: They are imported. Still crashes at launch.

Comment: no. I mean add them to the question. the error says : you are referencing to a none exist view inside your fragment

Comment: But the crazy thing is, they are referenced and called correctly. No errors. It accepts my class names and layout ID's for the corresponding fragments. When I load my app with my default code, without the append in the onCreate method, I can click the Home fragment and it takes me to that activity.

Comment: maybe a view that exists somewhere not inside the fragment.add the files

Comment: did you replace `content_fram` in my answer with `use app_bar_main`.
If yes. this is the problem . you have to replace it with your container id. that is inside your main

Comment: why you cant just add your all your files and error stack?.I am tired of guessing

Answer (score 0):

call the fragment in your onCreate

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1());
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: The app crashes at startup after appending this code with my values.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a004e (com.example.computer.finaltedford:id/home) for fragment Home{bbcc3cb #0 id=0x7f0a004e} –

Comment: But all my class fragments are correct and the corresponding views

Comment: you don't have the view with that id in your layout , use the framelayout view you've given in your layout xml